# How to access a variable among multiple javascript files

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i have 2 html pages and 2 java script pages,say
  `h1.html,h2.html
j1.js,j2.js` 
where can i declare a variable so that the variable can be accessible between both of java script and html files
 i want to initialize a value to that variable in first java script file and access that value in the second java script file

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access variable values across two html files even after the page loads you can use `localStorage` in js.
say if you want to set a value for a variable `localStorage.setItem("newvariable", 'variablevalue');` and for getting value use this `var getValue = localStorage.getItem("newvariable");`

**EDIT:**

for your base question refer those js files one by one

```
<script src="j1.js"></script>
<script src="j2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can declare the variable in any javascript file, and just include the file next to the other javascript file forexample.

```
// for example if you have file1.js like this.
var myvalue = 25;
```

You can then save this file and include it in your main or other html files for example at the bottom of your html document.

```
<html>
  <body> </body>
  <script src='file1.js'></script> // put the javascript file with your variable declaration on top of the other file you want to access the value from.
  <script src='file2.js'></script>
</html>
```

after the above you can then just print the variable in 'file2.js' like this.

```
// inside file2.js
console.log(myvalue) // which was declared in the 'file1.js'
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can bring your javascripts in to the `<head>` of your html then you can refer to the javascript as a function passing values as a parameter and returning data as well.
PS Don't forget to declare the javascript on your form.